# PowerShell script in Azure DevOps removes quotes

Tags: azure-devops

I have a PowerShell script that triggers a command, in this case it's a npx command. One of the arguments for the command contains spaces, locally it works fine but on Azure DevOps it seems like it drops the quotes. This because the script fails complaining about the value of the argument, which is everything until the first occurrence of a space.

The PowerShell script looks a bit simplified like this:

```
npx testcafe "$env:TESTCAFE_BROWSER_NAME" tests/**/*
```

The value of the environment variable could be something like `chrome@87.0:OS X Catalina`

The error in Azure Devops would the be something like:

```
ERROR Unable to find the browser. "chrome@87.0:OS" is not a browser alias or path to an executable file.
```

When running the script on my local machine with the same value for the environment variable it succeeds without any errors.

Comment: You can try to run with a self-hosted agent, will you get the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below workarounds to keep the quotes in the script.

1, you can use back tick "`" to escape the quotes. See below:

```
npx testcafe "`"$env:TESTCAFE_BROWSER_NAME`"" tests/**/*
```

2, Yon can aslo define the value with the quotes in environment Variables. Define the environment variable in the Variables tab like below:

[image]